# Manipulating a data set that another thread is using

Tags: ruby, multithreading, concurrency

I have sinatra set up, listening for commits from a github repo. The system I currently have sets up, listens for a post, then pushes the payload to a payload array. I then call

```
@@payloads.each do .... whatever
```

If multiple posts come in from github, i.e., people push more commits while `@@payloads.each` is running, what happens? If there is one payload, then another gets pushed, does the `payloads.each` call circle another time? Or is it set up so that the number of payloads the `.each` call goes through is set in stone once the call is made?

Comment: Is the `@@payloads` array a standard ruby array?

Comment: On Stack Overflow, we expect you to have tried the code you want to ask about, and then ask after you've encountered an error, not stop and ask for advice before you try something. See http://sscce.org/ for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a FYI, you can run into problems reading/writing to the same array unless you syncronize the accesses. Look at Ruby's built-in [Queue](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/thread/rdoc/Queue.html) class. It's part of Thread.

You can have multiple producers/consumers which won't collide. Here's what the documentation says:

> This class provides a way to synchronize communication between threads.
>
> Example:

```
    require 'thread'

    queue = Queue.new

    producer = Thread.new do
      5.times do |i|
        sleep rand(i) # simulate expense
        queue << i
        puts "#{i} produced"
      end
    end

    consumer = Thread.new do
      5.times do |i|
        value = queue.pop
        sleep rand(i/2) # simulate expense
        puts "consumed #{value}"
      end
    end

    consumer.join
```

As far as using `each` to loop over the array, I think syntactically you should use:

```
loop do
  break if @@payloads.empty?
end
```

`each` implies a finite set of elements to iterate over. The description says:

> Calls the given block once for each element in self....

In other languages you can't change the container you're iterating over because the number of elements is set at the start of the loop; Attempting to change the container will raise an error. Relying on `each` allowing you to do that could lead to expectations you'll see that behavior in other languages; In my mind you're relying on a side-effect, or a side-door, which isn't a good practice.

[`loop`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) doesn't imply that because it's a simple loop you have to conditionally break out of using your own logic. Here's the example for `loop`:

```
loop do
  print "Input: "
  line = gets
  break if !line or line =~ /^qQ/
  # ...
end
```

There is no assumption of the number of elements, it's entirely open-ended. And, it's easy to break out because Queue has that necessary [`empty?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/thread/rdoc/Queue.html#method-i-empty-3F) method.

That's my $0.02 and how I'd do it.

Take a look at the "Related" threads on the right side of the page to get additional ideas.

Answer (score 1):

As long as `@@payloads` is a standard ruby array, the pushed payloads should get included in the `#each` iteration.

When one thread is iterating over an array, and another thread appending to the same array, the iterating thread will include the appended items.

[Take a look at this gist](https://gist.github.com/joonty/6000969) which has a simple program to demonstrate this behaviour. One thread iterates while another adds to the array. The outcome is potentially different every time, due to the nature of thread scheduling in ruby.